Export data from Excel via an API
I’m currently working on a project that requires me to import data from various excel documents onto a webpage. I can easily import the data via an API, the problem is getting that data out of excel.
I’ve successfully created a script via the script lab addin that enables me to pull all required data out of excel and format it. I’m even able to send it into script lab’s paired html display page. The problem, though, is that I am unsure if it’s possible to send the data elsewhere. Script lab is cloud based so in theory I can send it to an api from there, but I don’t know if it’s possible to import the api library into script lab’s JavaScript text editor. Alternatively, I would have no problem running the script locally on my device and sending the api calls from my computer. However, then I don’t know how to access the data in my excel document. It would all be local at that point so I could in theory do so easily, but I don’t know for sure. Am I just missing something or is this not possible? Is there a different way I should go about this?

What have you tried so far and what have the results been?

So I briefly looked into importing the api's library into script lab's javascript but I couldn't figure that out. I also tried looking into referencing the excel spreadsheet externally from a local script outside of excel, but couldn't figure that out either. I don't think it would be possible to reference my excel sheet from a cloud based script engine(excluding script lab). In theory, both of the above could/should be possible, but frankly I've only ever used javascript in closed HTML environments so API calls are new to me.
